# Python smtp email program works in mac but not in windows 10

Tags: python, windows, email, smtp, firewall

```
try:  
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    print("Initializing....")
    server.starttls()
    server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
    server.sendmail(sent_from, to, msg.as_string())
    server.close()
    print 'Email sent!'

except smtplib.SMTPException as e:  
    print 'Something went wrong...'
    print (str(e))
```

This code sends email when I am using it on mac.
It throws error on windows 10:

```
socket.error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

Also telnet smtp.gmail.com 587 works on the windows 10 machine. 
No antivirus is installed on the windows machine.

Comment: Correct indentation is vital in Python. I tried to fix your code and I was probably able to guess right, but please review; and please review [formatting help](/help/formatting) before you post again.  Thanks.

Comment: @tripleee the same code works on mac system and not on windows. so its not indentation issue.

Comment: I'm simply commenting on the need to be careful when posting Python questions on Stack Overflow. Your question could even end up being closed for being unclear if you mess it up badly enough that we can't guess what your actual code looks like.

Comment: Okay.  Finally figured the problem.
Need to add the inbound and outbound TCP rule and restart the system